# Attempt to index nil with 'Instance'

Tags: lua, roblox

I wanted to create a system for knock-back on my Roblox game but I don't really understand Lua script, I somehow fixed most of the bugs except this one.

**Error:**

> Players.SomePlayer.Backpack.Sword.Server:209: attempt to index nil with 'Instance'  -  Server - Server:209

**Script:**
**hrp value** ->

```
local hrp = character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
```

**Line with error** ->

```
local bv = Instance.new("BodyVelocity", ray.Instance.Parent:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart"))
```

**Params and ray** ->

```
local Params = RaycastParams.new()
Params.FilterDescendantsInstances = {character} --- remember to define our character!
Params.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist

local ray = workspace:Raycast(hrp.Position, hrp.CFrame.LookVector * 100, Params)

if ray then
    if humanoid.Health == 0 then return end
    if ray.Instance.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and not ray.Instance.Parent:FindFirstChild("db") then
        local eHum = ray.Instance.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

        local x = Instance.new("BoolValue", ray.Instance.Parent)
        x.Name = "db"
        game.Debris:AddItem(x, .7)
    end
end
```

I tried changing the humanoid root part parent, tried reducing some parts of the script and removing unnecessary parts and lines. However this did not work.

Comment: Heyo, where is the line with the error in the actual script? The error implies that `ray` doesn't exist, but I don't know where the `local bv` line is relative to your other code.

Comment: elseif Combo == 5 then
   hitAnim1:Play()

   local back = Vector3.new(0,0,-3)
   local up = Vector3.new(0,-3,0)

   local bv = Instance.new("BodyVelocity", ray.Instance.Parent:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart"))
   bv.Name = "Knockback"
   bv.MaxForce = Vector3.new(math.huge,math.huge,math.huge)
   bv.Velocity = hrp.CFrame.LookVector * 75 + back + up
   game.Debris:AddItem(bv, .1)
  end
this is the line 209 (aka. the line that has the error)

Comment: this script is working with the 'Params and ray' part of the script, i hope this helps you identifying the problem, if you want more info about it just tell me